# R. Axis label for box plot stacking redundantly stacking over eachother

Tags: r

Making boxplot. Specifying the axes separately. Heres the code.

```
boxplot(data$overall~data$league, horizontal=T, las=2, axes='n', outpch=20,
 outcex=.5, cex.axis=.5, col=rainbow(7, alpha=.5))
axis(1, lty=1, at=seq(45,90,5))
axis(2, at=data$league, labels=as.character(data$league), las=2, cex.axis=.3)
```

It takes a long time to run the line that puts the axis there, and the words look so weird and blurry.  That makes me think they are getting stacked on top of each other. How do I prevent this?

[image]

Also, how do I flip the y-axis (`data$league`) from Z-A sort to an A-Z sort?

Comment: Also, data$league is a factor if that's relevant.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(data)`?

Comment: `.Names = c("league", "overall"), row.names = c(NA, -17994L), class = "data.frame")`. It also has a bunch of 60L's and 59L's and more